# Could not fetch remote template - Tempest

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

I am trying to create heat stack using yaml file in tempest.
I have 2 yaml files. 
I have to execute first file. Second file is refered in the first file

> server_group autoscale group and it's init contents to generate load
>     scale_group:
>       type: OS::Heat::AutoScalingGroup
>       properties:
>         min_size: 1
>         max_size: 3
>         resource:
>           type: SimpleServerWithPoolMember.yaml

I get below error when i run the function

StackBuildErrorException: Stack e3f16f15-6001-4404-a7c0-999fc114df1b is in CREATE_FAILED status due to 'Resource CREATE failed: StackValidationFailed: Could not fetch remote template 'SimpleServerWithPoolMember.yaml': Invalid URL scheme '

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug for openstack-heat, and it can be reproduced on version 0.2.8.

If you want to avoid this issue, my suggestion is try to update your version to 0.2.12.

Comment: For those who fail in the same issue, the workaround is to use template with environment file as explain here : http://docs.openstack.org/developer/heat/template_guide/composition.html#define-a-new-resource-type I hope this helps.